# Convert multiple List of lists (paragraphs) into HTML numbered spans

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list

The purpose of my code is to create a JS translator tool that displays the translated word when you click on it (English words shown but onClick shows Spanish). Due to a bigger plethora of word tokenization packages in Python, I have to use Python and then transpile the Python to HTML (with the JS inline to create self-contained files). The onClick/`reveal` function is mostly solved and now I am stuck on the issue below ...

I have 2 lines of text like so:

> Hello. My name is Joe

> I am a boy

I have stored these 2 lines into list of lists like so:

`L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]`

and

`L2 = [['I', 'am', 'a', 'boy'],['Soy', 'un', 'el', 'niño']]`

I want to use these lists of lists to get this output:

```html
<p>
<span id="w0" onclick="reveal(0)"> </span> &nbsp;. <span id="w1" onclick="reveal(1)"></span><span id="w2" onclick="reveal(2)"></span><span id="w3" onclick="reveal(3)"><span id="w4" onclick="reveal(4)"><span id="w5" onclick="reveal(5)">
</p>
<p>
<span id="w6" onclick="reveal(6)"> </span> <span id="w7" onclick="reveal(7)"></span><span id="w8" onclick="reveal(8)"></span><span id="w9" onclick="reveal(9)">
</p>
```

I could use code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224657/python-list-of-lists-anf-html-table-help) to convert into a single entry, but the problems I am facing are:

1. How do I keep a count from sub-list (paragraph) to sub-list (paragraph) such that I can go from L1 to L2 while also going from `w5` to `w6` (and from `span` to `span`)
2. When encountering full stops, I would like to add them as text in between spans like so: `</span> &nbsp;. <span id="w1"`

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understood nr.1 of your questions but an answer for your second problem could be solved by storing the string you get from concatenating the arrays in a variable, and then using the str.replace() function.

Would look something like this.

```
str.replace(".", "&nbsp;.")
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the 1st question less unclear?

Comment: Not completely sure to be honest. Also I just went through your code snippet and I realized that what I talked about in my answer won't really work because what I thought you did was concatenate the string and then rendering it, but it turns out you did it word per word. So I will post another answer soon, that I think will be more optimized than this.